# Flow matrix from Earth Mover's Distance

Tags: opencv, histogram

I was reading some paper and it said:

> By adopting the **Earth Mover's Distance (EMD)** algorithm, a **flow matrix**
>   f = {fij} from one histogram to another can be obtained.

I found an implementation for EMD in OpenCV. However, this implementation looks like:

```
float EMDL1(InputArray signature1, InputArray signature2);
```

It returns a single float value rather than a flow matrix. Is there a way to obtain the flow matrix using OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was Writing the post I found the answer. It might help someone...

There is another function which is:

```
float EMD(InputArray signature1, InputArray signature2, int distType, InputArray cost=noArray(), float* lowerBound=0, OutputArray flow=noArray() );
```

`flow` is an output parameter that return the flow matrix.